# Ruby On Rails - Image Tag Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know how to specify the full URL src attibute in image_tag?

Currently I use:

```
image_tag(object.team.team_logo, :alt => object.team.name)
```

And the src attibute is transformed incorrectly into:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets/%20http://a.espncdn.com/i/teamlogos/soccer/500/103.png
```

I tried runing rake assets:precompile && rake assets:clean_expired but the app still treats the full url as a precompiled asset.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to properly clean and validate your `team_logo` values before putting them in the database: the first character of your `object.team.team_logo` value is a space.

If you trace through the `image_tag` implementation, you'll find that it eventually calls [`asset_path`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b15ce4a006756a0b6cacfb9593d88c9a7dfd8eb0/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L120):

```
def asset_path(source, options = {})
  source = source.to_s
  return "" unless source.present?
  return source if source =~ URI_REGEXP
  #...
```

You have a leading space in `team_logo` so the `URI_REGEXP` test fails and Rails will prepend the asset path (and URL encode the string, hence the `%20` representation of your space).

You should do a few things:

1. Add a validation to your model to ensure that `team_logo` is always a well formed URL.
2. Add a `before_validation` callback to your model to clean up any stray whitespace in incoming `team_logo` values.
3. Go through all the `team_logo` values in your database and clean them up, you'll probably need to repair or delete some of them by hand.

Once you've cleaned up your data, your `image_tag` will work as expected.

I suppose you could strip off the whitespace in your view that's pretty nasty and should not be done unless you need an immediate fix to keep the business from failing in the next five minutes. And even then, you'd want to clean up the data and backout the "clean up whitespace in the view" kludge right away.